# How to resolve error of passing email in rest api url at end position?

Tags: c#, rest, webapi

I am creating a GET Rest api

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{email}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers(string email)
        {
           //rest of the code
        }
```

When I hit the api from Postman, it gave **IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found**

It works when I put a trailing '/' after the email in URL, but I don't want to use that, is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: If you are providing "users", I'd suggest having the email as a querystring filter instead, like `/api/users?email=someEmail`. This is not an answer of course, just a suggestion on how to better model your route that could maybe work around the problem at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I allow URL encoded path segments in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178949/how-do-i-allow-url-encoded-path-segments-in-azure)

Comment: So, it works when you call /test@test.com/ and doesn't work /test@test.com ?

Comment: @godot correct.. dont work for /test@test.com

Comment: To fix this, you can modify your **routing configuration** to allow requests without the trailing slash. In your **WebApiConfig.cs** file, add the following line of code:

`config.UrlTrailingSlashMode = System.Web.Http.TrailingSlashMode.Optional;`