# I want that this returns as a single entire thing. For example, if i input the value 10/26 in the object it reads as part of the input

Tags: c#, .net, angular, http

I have an Angular + .NET Application with a method for searching a specific `ConsumerUnit`.

Right now, if I give an example input like `10/2689123`, it considers the `/` as part of the URL endpoint and not as part of the search value.

How can I solve this?

It *works in my localhost environment*, but when I upload to Azure the request returns 404 and is not able to find a number that matches. It works properly if I search for a number without a `/`.

Here is my Angular Service part:

```
search(word: string): Observable<ConsumerUnit[]> {
        const encodedWord = encodeURIComponent(word);
        return this.http.get<ConsumerUnit[]>(this.url + `/search/${encodedWord}`, this.header())
          .pipe(map((resp: any) => {
            return resp.data as ConsumerUnit[];
          }),
          catchError(null));
      }
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search/{encodedWord}")]
[Authorize("ReadConsumerUnit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSearch(string encodedWord)
{
    var result = await _consumerUnitAppService.SearchByNameOrDocumentAsync(encodedWord);
    return Response(true, result);
}
```

And Here is the Method  that my controller is calling:

```
public async Task<List<ConsumerUnitDto>> SearchByNameOrDocumentAsync(string nameOrDocument)
{
    IQueryable<ConsumerUnit> query = Service.GetByExpression(x => x.Active);

    nameOrDocument = Uri.UnescapeDataString(nameOrDocument); 
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameOrDocument))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(nameOrDocument) || x.Document.Contains(nameOrDocument) || x.Number.Contains(nameOrDocument));

    }
    var list = await query.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToListAsync();

    return Mapper.Map<List<ConsumerUnitDto>>(list);
}
```

I tried to encoding the word in my front-end and decoding after in my back-end, but it didn't work.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(word)` should work and you don't need to decode it at the backend.

Comment: encodeURIComponent in my localhost works, but when i upload to my server in Azure Websites, it doesn't. Maybe it could be a error related there?

Comment: It might be related to Azure Websites, so adding the proper tag would help you better, as someone who has expertise with Azure Websites sees this question. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178949/how-do-i-allow-url-encoded-path-segments-in-azure) question helps.

Comment: Try logging the value you receive on server. That will most likely give you the answer

Answer (score 0):

We have this attribute on the search method:

```
[Route("search/{encodedWord}")]
```

When you have a search value with a `/` that is not URL-encoded, the search *no longer matches the route*, which perfectly explains a 404 response. Even if it did match the route it would only match for the `encodedWord` variable up to the `/`, with any remaining text lost.

But we have this:

> I tried to encoding the word in my front-end

and we see this to back it up:

```
const encodedWord = encodeURIComponent(word);
```

However, we also see this:

> It works in my localhost environment, but when I upload to Azure the request returns 404

I suggest making sure the Azure environment is actually serving the updated code, and that the browser is running the updated code rather than a cached version of the page.